# How to point requireJS text plugin to an MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs, requirejs-text

I want to load HTML from an ASP.NET MVC 4 action. So full URL looks like:

`http://localhost:7588/en/Dialogs/AclManager`

Here is how I declare dependency:

```
define(['jquery', 'text!AclManager'], function...
```

Here is my `require.config` excerpt:

```
require.config({ paths: { 'AclManager' : '/en/Dialog/AclManager' }});
```

With this configuration text plugin doesn't find extension and tries to load: `/scripts/.AclManager`

if I declare dependency as `AclManager.` (notice dot), then require goes to `/en/Dialogs/AclManager.' which is almost right, except that dot at the end.

I could declare dependency as `AclManager/.` and this works because my server will ignore trailing `/`, but I would rather not have a trailing slash there.

What would be an easy way to point text to the URL I need?

Comment: I don't think you should  put mvc action urls into the require.js config, it's only meant for libs, modules and plugins. That's how I understand it.